# VBA Excel Delete Rows if Certain Numbers do not exist

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying delete entire rows if certain numbers do not exist in Column B. For example, unless the cell in Column B contains "812", "820", or "840", delete entire row.

Rows 1 and 2 are a header. Data starts on Row 3. Length of ws is always changing.

If it matters, the numbers listed in Column B are formatted as "General".

Please help. I have searched and tested for days. Either everything is deleting or nothing is.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you post the code you do have?

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you. To implement, Open **VBE** > Paste code on **sheet** where you want code to execute.

When you are deleting rows, it is a best practice to work your way from the bottom up. Therefore, this will loop through your values in B from the lastrow (`LRow`) up to row 3.
**If** the value matches your target value, it will simply move on to the next row (above).
**If** the value does not match your target, it will delete the entire row.

```
Sub RowScrub()

Dim LRow As Long, I As Long
LRow = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For I = LRow To 3 Step -1
    If Range("B" & I).Value <> 812 And Range("B" & I).Value <> 820 And Range("B" & I).Value <> 840 Then
        Range("B" & I).EntireRow.Delete
    End If
Next I

End Sub
```

Comment: ok, now I follow the logic, neat ...

Comment: Yes, I can see it now - long day... plus 1 from me!

Comment: This works Perfect. Incredible. I wasn't even in the right ballpark. Thank you.